# Why is my thread getting blocked on urlopen?

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2, cx-freeze, urlopen

```
while 1:
    try:
        print "It is getting blocked here"
        jsonResponse=urlopen(request).read()
        print "It is not reaching here"
        break
    except:

        tries+=1
        print "retry after 10 seconds",tries
        time.sleep(10)
        if tries>5:
            print "Some Other time"
            raise Exception('Server did not respond
```

This code is part of a larger thread representing a User Interface
A peculiar thing is it works fine when I run it using python but when **I build it using cx_freeze** and then run the .exe it blocks at urlopen()

Comment: `urlopen` may block. Fire up wireshack and see how it communicates.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? What version of cx_Freeze? Can you post a simple script that demonstrates the problem and is actually runnable?